# What's the best way to run a linqpad script from your release pipeline?

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration, azure-devops, linqpad, continuous-delivery

I have a `linqpad` script which we need to run as part of our release, from `VSTS`. Best way I can think of is to run this as a `Powershell` script. There seem to be 2 options to be able to do this

1. Linqpad's native `lprun.exe`
2. Linqpadless `lpless.exe`

The problem with these however is that I will have to install these on the Build/Release VMs for each environment, which is what I'm trying to avoid at the moment.

Linqpadless does distribute a nuget package but I don't know how to run that from powershell/release pipeline.

Has anyone done something similar. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Why not just implement your script in PowerShell?

Comment: Yeah, that's the long term view. This is something we need integrated quickly. It contains some logic, especially around filesystem read/write with excel apis that will take a bit to port to Ps1.

Comment: Using Nuget packages from PowerShell is currently more cumbersome than it should be - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6724. Perhaps the information there will help to craft a workaround.

Comment: I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: I am afraid that you need to setup linqpad on the build/release agent.

Answer (score 1):

You can add three tasks in your build definition to do this:

1. Nuget Task to install linqpadless package:
   [image]
2. Command Line task to run lpless.exe:
   [image]
3. Command Line task to run the script generated by lpless.exe in last step:
   [image]

If you want to use Powershell script, you just need to call these command in the script one by one.